# I only wish to hide my IP from services like Spotify? Is Tor good for that?

Tags: ip-address

If I'm in certain countries I can no longer access services like Netflix and spotify etc.  Tor seems to hide IP addresses completely and I'm wondering if these services I want to access will even work if no IP address is detected.

If Tor is appropriate, is it easy to set up on Mac OS X Yosemite?

Thanks

Comment: No, use something simpler like hola.org

Answer (score 3):

Tor is likely not the solution you're looking for, as most services that do geolocation to block users not in a certain country block anonymizers.

Tor doesn't hide your IP address completely, Tor makes it appear that your IP address is that of the Tor exit node. This means that the service you're trying to access will also see the IP address of the Tor node.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there will be always an IP that's detected. Tor just hides *your* IP and replaces it with that of the exit-node you're using.

Even though Tor's goal isn't what you're looking for, it's feasible to use it for your purposes, but it might require a bit more work than simply installing the Tor Browser Bundle in order to work consistently:
You either need to configure Tor to give you an exit-node of a certain country via the `ExitNodes` command in Tor's configuration file (`torrc`), or every time you start your Tor Browser you need to check if the site you want works, and if not, request a new identity until it works.

Setting up Tor is quite easy. You only need to download the Tor Browser Bundle [here](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to hide your identity, in fact you're likely logging into your own account anyway. The better option is to use a VPN for what you're trying to achieve. This will allow you to appear as if you're in a certain country (many VPN services allow you to choose from a range of countries) so that you can use the account you need.

Comment: I strongly disagree with that sentiment. Just because I log into a service doesn't mean I want anyone but the service to know I'm doing it, not even the VPN provider.

Comment: That's true, but from the original question it seems the concern is only related to using Spotify/Netflix in other countries. This is a common question and *usually* a VPN is the desired solution when anonymity isn't inherently required.